# Can i set a php variable value to a html element that is being manipulated by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im sorry I didnt know how to phrase my question well, but i have my php code:

```
<div class="header">
        <h1>Space Invaders</h1>
        <p style="color: yellow;">.</p>
    </div>
    <h1 class="results">SCORE: 0</h1>
    <?php
    $results = "results";
    if ($results == 'YOU WIN') {
        echo("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
    }
    ?>
```

and i have my script that will change the text at class results when the game finishes it will say "YOU WIN"
Okay so now i want to make a if statment in php when the results transforms into "YOU WIN".
I just cant figure a way out, sorry about my english too.

Comment: PHP is run on the server, before JS runs. Use your javascript to change an elements HTML to `You win`, not PHP. Or use AJAX to send the score to a PHP script that validates if the user has won

Comment: I know, sorry i didnt explain well, but JS is already doing that , i just need is php to detect that change , do you get it ?

Comment: I got it the first time already, yes. But without AJAX PHP will not detect _any_ changes made to the CLIENT, PHP is run on the SERVER.

Comment: To get PHP to execute after the Javascript, you must either use JavaScript, or post back a form from the page, or have the browser navigate to a new URL.